# Polymerfire error on production

Tags: firebase, polymer, firebase-authentication, polymerfire

My project works fine locally and when I deploy it to Firebase Hosting. Also works fine on Edge, but doesn't work in Chrome when I deploy it. I get the error shown below. I think that the "auth" process never finished, but I don't know why :(

[image]

The code is very simple:

```
signIn: function () {
  var that = this;
  this.$.auth.signInWithPopup()
    .then(function (res) {
      that.fire('feedback-positivo', 'Has iniciado sesión');
      that.saveProfile(res.user, res.credential);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log('Error', error.message, error.code);
    });
},
```

Comment: I had this problem.  Check your polymer.json file and make sure you have all your views in the fragments array.  Not 100% sure that's what fixed it

Comment: Thanks Ryan, but that is not my problem :(